# Using sed to cut and add to specific lines of diff output

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, regular-expression, diff

I have the output from my diff command between two directories store in a file called `differenceOutput.txt`.

At present there are only two kinds of lines in `differenceOutput.txt` So all lines have either format A or B, where A and B look like this:

A)

```
Only in /tmp/__tmp_comp206_alex/test_files/: file_1.txt
```

B)

```
Files /tmp/__tmp_comp206_alex/test_files/file_3.conf and /tmp/__tmp_comp206_alex/diff_dir/file_3.conf differ
```

Using `sed`, I want to change all lines in `differenceOutput.txt` with format A to format C, and all lines with format B to format D, where C and D look like this:

C)

```
/tmp/__tmp_comp206_alex/test_files/file_1.txt is missing
```

D)

```
/tmp/__tmp_comp206_alex/diff_dir/file_3.conf differs
```

How can I do this with `sed`? Super confused with the sed syntax. I've spent hours trying to figure this out but can't make heads or tails of this. Can someone help me out please?

Comment: This is very easy with the specific examples you show, but can get extremely complicated for complex file names. Can your file names contain spaces? Can they contain newlines? Can your file names contain a `:`? Can they contain an `and` surrounded by spaces?

Comment: i can assume that my filenames contain none of things for this particular case

Comment: Then roaima's answer should be perfect for you. Do read his final note about using `cmp` though.

Comment: it doesn't work for me. Can you help me implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '
    sub(/^Only in /,"") { sub(/: /,""); $0=$0 " is missing" }
    sub(/^Files /,"")   { sub(/ and .*/,""); $0=$0 " differs" }
1' differenceOutput.txt
/tmp/__tmp_comp206_alex/test_files/file_1.txt is missing
/tmp/__tmp_comp206_alex/test_files/file_3.conf differs
```

That assumes your directory names don't contain `:<blank>` or `<blank> and <blank>` and none of your file/dir names contain newlines.

The above was tested using this file created from the sample input you provided in your question:

```
$ cat differenceOutput.txt
Only in /tmp/__tmp_comp206_alex/test_files/: file_1.txt
Files /tmp/__tmp_comp206_alex/test_files/file_3.conf and /tmp/__tmp_comp206_alex/diff_dir/file_3.conf differ
```

Comment: hey ed, thanks for your comment. I feel like everybody has misinterpreted the questions a little bit, which is why it only partially works, and it seems impossible to explain through the comments here given how slow it is. Can I show you my code if u 5 have minutes? https://codeshare.io/2pB8p4 we can chat in real time there and i can actually exlain what it going on with my code there. Would appreciate it tons!!

Comment: Just edit your question to show a few lines of sample input and expected output that the posted solutions don't work for - that should be all that's needed. I personally am happy to help with a couple minutes of my time here and there when someone asks a reasonably clear question but I'm not interested in discussions or code walkthroughs to try to understand the problem (not for free anyway!), maybe others will be able to help if that's what you feel it'll take.

Comment: I got the code to work!!! YOU THE REAL MVP ED!!! All SED and DONE, awk > sed CONFIRMED

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. Two straightforward `sed` substitutions

```
a='Only in /tmp/__tmp_comp206_alex/test_files/: file_1.txt'
b='Files /tmp/__tmp_comp206_alex/test_files/file_3.conf and /tmp/__tmp_comp206_alex/diff_dir/file_3.conf differ'

printf "%s\n%s\n" "$a" "$b" |
sed -e 's!^Only in \([^:]*\)/: \(.*\)!\1/\2 is missing!' -e 's!^Files .* and \(.*\) differ$!\1 differs!'
```

Output

```
/tmp/__tmp_comp206_alex/test_files/file_1.txt is missing
/tmp/__tmp_comp206_alex/diff_dir/file_3.conf differs
```

Explanation

- I've used `!` instead of `/` as the separator in the `sed` recipe `s/match/replacement/` since otherwise we'd have to escape every occurrence of `/` in the match and replacement strings
- The `\1` and `\2` in the replacement match escape-bracketed expressions (ie `\(...\)`) in the match part

The big assumption is that you don't have filenames containing colons and other matching words from the `diff` output. The `diff` output is fragile at best and you might be better off rolling your own loop with `find` and `cmp -s` that produced the desired output directly. (That would be my preference for a robust solution.)

```
#!/bin/bash
src='/tmp/__tmp_comp206_alex/test_files'
dst='/tmp/__tmp_comp206_alex/diff_dir'

( cd "$src" && find -type f -print0 ) |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' item
    do
        if [[ ! -f "$dst/$item" ]]
        then
            printf "%s is missing\n" "$dst/$item"

        elif ! cmp -s "$src/$item" "$dst/$item"
        then
            printf "%s differs\n" "$dst/$item"
        fi
    done
```

Comment: Thank you!! Sorry if this is a silly question, but how do I use this code to update the differenceOutput.txt, and then print that to screen?

Comment: Create a new file, then replace the old one with the new

Comment: i'm still pretty confused about how to actually do this. One of my friends did a one liner in their script like this and it did the job:  sed -e "s/Only in $ogdir: /\/$1\//g" -e "s/Only in $compdir: /\/$2\//g" -e '/^\// s/$/ is missing/' -e 's/^F.*and //' -e '/differ/ s/$/s/' < output_diff.txt

Comment: Is there a way I can implement something similar?

Comment: @user140161 this _is_ something similar. Almost identical, really. Just take roaima's sed command and run it on your file: `sed -e 's!^Only in \([^:]*\)/: \(.*\)!\1/\2 is missing!' -e 's!^Files .* and \(.*\) differ$!\1 differs!' yourFile.txt`

Comment: doesn't work. Could it be that where it says alex my actually code actually has  jksakl6 (six lower case letters followed by a number). I changed the name in the post for privacy purposes, but maybe that's causing the issue?

Comment: @user140161 Can you get the example I've demonstrated in the top of my answer to produce the output I've shown it produces?

Comment: I've sort of figured out the issue. The problem is only for files where the my script produces files with extenions .sh and .conf How can I edit this to accommodate those files?

Comment: @user140161 you don't need to edit it as long as your list is in the format you described

Comment: ok let me give you some more details that might help you understand what the problem is here. I'll show you my code. Can you come here for 5 minutes? It's a code collab thing where we can talk and write code in real time https://codeshare.io/2pB8p4

Comment: i'm waiting for you there if you're gonna show up, or if somebody else reading this who understands this is and is willing to give 5 minutes of their time